# Laravel 5 route parameters not send

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

With Laravel 5 I'm not able to setup get route parameters.

My route is setup like this:

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@test');
```

And my TestController looks like this:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->input('foo'));
}
```

When I browse to that route with a parameter

```
/test?foo=bar
```

the result is NULL.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The Input::get('foo') syntax doesn't work either (and is not even mentioned in the documentation for L5).

**Update:**

I'm using Apache as webserver.

I have also tried

```
$request->get('foo')
```

and a route like this

```
Route::get('test/{foo?}', 'TestController@test');
```

with the same URL and still get null.

**Update 2:**

The documentation of L5 gives examples for routes like this:

```
/test/bar
```

instead of

```
/test?foo=bar
```

In L4 it was possible to browse to routes with GET like

```
/test?foo=bar&id=2&user=admin
```

or changing the order

```
/test?id=2&user=admin&foo=bar
```

with one and the same route

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@test');
```

and all you had to do was get it with

```
Input::get('user')
```

But with L5 it wouldn't be possible to change the order of parameters when you have to use slashes in the routes like

```
Route::get('test/{id}/{user}/{foo}', 'TestController@test');
```

Is this really a big downgrade for routes in L5?

Comment: I do not know why it does not work for you, but here is a proof that you can access `GET` params using `\Illuminate\Http\Request`: http://prntscr.com/6viqmv. Maybe something wrong with your apache setup.

Comment: And that really return "bar" in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, checked the screen on mobile and didn't see the complete image. Is this running versin 5 of Laravel on apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `.htaccess` file, I used an edited one where the parameters didn't get send.

With the default `.htaccess` file that comes with the Framework everything works!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this with extracts from your `.htaccess` file.
Might make it useful for future

Comment: I am running into same issue. Can u please elaborate  about the htaccess solution?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the `.htaccess` solution?

Comment: I didn't edit my `.htaccess` but still doesn't work. I'm using Lumen.

Answer (score 0):

*Would you try this?*

```
use Request;

public function test(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->get('foo'));
}
```

Comment: Tried it, still the result is null. I will update my question.

Comment: And change route to Route::get('test', 'TestController@test');
You do not have to use the route's parameter for GET Request.

Comment: I also tried that, still doesn't work. Is it possible to setup a test on your machine to make sure that it really is laravel that is not working here?

Comment: maybe you can test it(server) with a new laravel installer.

Comment: I have two setups with laravel, one installed with composer and the other one with the laravel installer 1.2.0 - both no difference, doesn't work.

Comment: What is the result of var_dump($_REQUEST). Would you try?

Comment: The result for that are 6 strings: route, __utma, __utmz, __ga, __pk_id..., laravel_session

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 you can put a param into controller method like this:

`public function test(Request $request, $foo)
{
}`

with route - Route::get('test/{foo}', 'TestController@test');`

Comment: That works only for /test/bar but not for /test?foo=bar. I have updated my question where I explain why this is not a good solution.

Comment: try to use `$_GET` array to getting your values.

Comment: That only gives me the complete route that was entered. And btw, you shouldn't need to use $_GET in laravel.