# How to pass data to another application through URl using Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, guzzle

I want to  send data from one application to another .. where i want to send the first application data to second application form..
For that I used guzzle. And the platform I used Laravel.

Here is the first application controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->username = $request->Input(['username']);
        $payment->price = $request->Input(['price']);
        $payment->purchase_id = $request->Input(['purchase_id']);
        $payment->save();
        $store_id =\Hash::make($payment->id);
        $price = $payment->price; 
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/b/public/api/getPayment/{store_id}',[
            'form_params'=>['store_id'=>$store_id]
            ]);
    }
```

And the second application form :

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'store', 'class'=>'form-horizontal','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
           {!! csrf_field() ; !!}                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Store ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="storeId" value="{{$store_id}}"  placeholder="Store ID">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And in second Controller I put the route in api.php

```
Route::get('/getPayment/{store_id}',[
    'uses'=>'PaymentController@create',
    'as'=>'create'
    ]);
```

But the problem I'm facing that I can't send the `store_id`through Guzzle.Because while I dd() the output I see the response `NULL`. Means I couldn't send the store_id through URL..Can anyone suggest me How I can pass the `form_parameter`

Comment: Do you have a different laravel for your second application or it resides in same place?

Comment: Different Laravel Application

Comment: just add this code  `return $response->getBody();` after your `$client->request()` and show us the response of that code

Comment: Same Error I'm getting means the above one..

Comment: I hope that the second application is not getting the form data you are posting or it might be creating the views. Just debug on your Route::get() whether the parameters are received or not. You could check by this example
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29723193/3887342

Comment: Yup, it's returning `null` when I dd() the route parameter ..
Then is there any wrong of parameter passing code in controller?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this block of code with two instance of laravel and it is working. You just need to add the `query` in the parameters your are passing.

Your First Application calling second application from here:

```
$data = [
   'query' => [ 'page' => '2']
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://127.0.0.2:8000/path', $data);
echo $response->getBody();
```

Now the route of Second Application which is being called by guzzle looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('/path', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->all();
});
```

So, your code needs to be changed as:

```
$data = [ 'query' =>   //<==add 'query' here
    ['form_params'=>
        ['store_id'=>$store_id]
    ]
];
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/b/public/api/getPayment', $data);
```

If you want to know more about the `query` string it is over here:

> http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

Hope it helps you.

**Edit:**

According to your need you might not need `guzzle` but to redirect to the location with extra parameters yoou need to use `redirect()` like:

```
return redirect()->to('http://127.0.0.2:8000?page=2');
```

I have tried `route()` and other `redirect()` methods but couldn't find any easy method to perform the task. If there is any simpler method anyone could correct me.

Comment: I have one Query, I can send the data to another application but one problem is there in route means with the request shouldn't it in other application?
because I see the name `http://localhost/a/public/store` whereas it should be `http://localhost/b/public/api/getPayment` why is that, can you give me a proper explanation please?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are telling. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Means While I'm sending data to another application in URL I'm seeing the old application link instead of the new one.

that's what I'm asking

Comment: @Hola Since we are only requesting from second application we are not changing the url. So, do you have a scenario used to change the url?

Comment: Yes sort of like that, because I want to reach the user to the second application. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: You might not need the `guzzle` to perform the task in my view. Please look at the updated answer